# How to create webapp, REST API and OAuth2 at the same server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I'm still learning spring and currently I'm trying to create webapplication and RESTful API at the same server. It was easy until I tried to add OAuth2 authorizaton to be able to consume that API in Android application.
I have a problem because I don't completely understand what is happening under the hood of spring.

I want achieve something like this:

1. localhost:8080**/** - webapp authorized in normal way
2. localhost:8080**/login** - webapp login page
3. localhost:8080**/api/** -RESTfull API
4. localhost:8080**/oauth/[authorize|token]** - OAuth2
5. Android application to consume API

Is it even possible? Can you provide an example code or just the way I should do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Spring Boot has plenty of documentation.

I'd recommend the [Spring Boot manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/)

As for what you want, yes, it's possible. 
See [this demo](https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo/) which has OAuth, REST API and normal HTML, CSS, JS files all in one. Also, this demo is based on spring-boot, so what more do you want :)

Again, the demo url:
https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo/

As I said above, it's possible. Not recommended, but possible. It would be recommended to split them, for a better separation of concerns. Also for performance reasons: Apache for instance can serve static files much  faster than SpringBoot/Tomcat can. 
Of course you can start this way and do it later. Enjoy.

Comment: I think that you have pasted the wrong link - both links directs to jwt-spring-security-demo.

Comment: that was my intention.. one demo to rule them all

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Take a look at JHipster and how they realize OAuth2. http://jhipster.github.io You can generate app and check how everything is done under the hood. You can also find many useful patterns for development.